# Воспроизведение звука в обратном порядке на android

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, не нашел подобной информации, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так перевернуть:

```
private void writeAudio() {
short[] shortArray = toShortArray(audioBuffer);
short[] reversedShortArray = reverseArray(shortArray);
byte[] reversedByteArray = toByteArray(reversedShortArray);
audioTrack.write(reversedByteArray, 0, bufferSize);
}

private short[] toShortArray(byte[] byteArray {
short[] shortArray = new short[byteArray.length / 2];
for (int i = 0 ; i < shortArray.length; i){
     shortArray[i] = (short)((short)byteArray[i*2] | (short)(byteArray[i*2 + 
1] << 8));
     // alternatively - depending on the endianess of the data:
     // shortArray[i] = (short)((short)byteArray[i*2] << 8 | (short) 
(byteArray[i*2 + 1]));
}
return shortArray;
}
```